# Python Remove Inline CSS From DIV

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, scripting

I want to remove inline CSS from following div:

```
<div style="width:100%;overflow-x:hidden;">
```

No class or id is present in div.
So, In python how can i remove the above inlinve CSS from that div?

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the style attribute of element by locating it using cssSelector as below.

```
$("div[style='width:100%;overflow-x:hidden;']").removeAttr("style")
```

OR

```
$("div[style='width:100%;overflow-x:hidden;']").removeAttribute("style")
```

Comment: OK, I'll import jQuery in my phython script then I'll let you know if it worked.